# Magento 2 How set db information in encrypted form

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

Is there any way to set the database information in the app/etc/env.php in encrypted form

For examples

```
  array (
          'indexer' => 
          array (
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'dbname' => 'dbname',
            'username' => 'encryptedUserName',
            'password' => 'encryptedUserpassword',
            'active' => '1',
            'persistent' => NULL,
          ),
          'default' => 
          array (
            'host' => 'localhost',
             'dbname' => 'dbname',
            'username' => 'encryptedUserName',
            'password' => 'encryptedUserpassword',
            'active' => '1',
          ),
        ),
```

Thank You!

Abbas

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

We need to implement the following steps

**Step 1:**

Set the value in the encrypted form in app/etc/env.php

**Step 2:**

Override the class vendor/magento/framework/App/ResourceConnection.php and decrypt the values in the function getConnectionByName

**Solution 2:**

Set the values using base64_decode.

```
array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'databasename',
        'username' => base64_decode('encoded user name'),
        'password' => base64_decode('encoded password'),
        'active' => '1',
        'persistent' => NULL,
      ),
```

Comment: The above mentioned steps to override ResourceConnection is not working, have you tried in your system, if yes can you share that code ?

Comment: Yes I have tried and it is working.

Comment: It's not working for me, it's showing error in adapter class of zend framework.
vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php

Comment: Can you share customized codebase ?